# Android & IOS Debug Log email or post remotely via webservice

Tags: android, ios

As and when I gave app to my client, I want all the application log to my email. So as and when any error occur or any crash report or any such application log, I want it to my email rather than my client complain me about features not working or something like that.

Can anyone give me some idea or way how to achieve it in Android and IOS?

Comment: this question is probably off topic for StackOverflow as it generates spam, but with that said take a look at [Crashlytics](http://try.crashlytics.com)

Answer (score 0):

You need to integrate crash reporter in your application like I am using [Crashlytics](https://crashlytics.com). You can also find others.